# Vue transition break focus on ios. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-transitions

I have button and textarea, which is invisible. When click on button textarea appears and is focused, the keyboard appears on ios(Safari), and the screen correctly scrolls to textarea.

However, if I wrap textarea with transition component screen does not scroll to textarea and textarea appears behind the keyboard. Please advise how I could have correct focus with transition?

I use vue 2.6.10

code example: https://jsitor.com/ZGmF0GPpqO

Comment: Somebody once said: A code tells more then 1000 words. Why dont you just copy paste your code in here?

Comment: @bill.gates add code example.